# Read only filesystem after ISPconfig instalation

Tags: boot, 16.04, filesystem, read-only, quota

I installed ISPconfig on my Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.  When I rebooted, it booted into command line instead of gui and the system is read only so i cannot make changes or uninstall what I did. The hostname at the top also does not say my server name, it says a subdomain name that was set during the ISPconfig installation.

Thanks for taking time to help me with this.

I have tried before and the output I get from `mount -o rw,remount /` is `mount: / not mounted or bad option`

The output from `fsck -f /` is `fsck from util-linux 2.27.1 
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015) 
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes 
Pass 2: Checking directory structure 
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity 
Pass 4: Checking reference counts 
Pass 5: Checking group summary information /dev/sda6: 332167/53886976 files (0.7% non-contiguous), 41586480/215535872`

Comment: How did you install ISPconfig... from a .deb file, or something else?

Comment: I ran an automated script found at https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ispconfig-automated-install-script/

Comment: I looked at that web page, and it clearly says that ISPconfig is for Ubuntu Servers... NOT Ubuntu Desktop!

Comment: I am using my ubuntu desktop as a server. I usually just SSH into it but I installed Desktop to have the option to use the GUI and remote into a windows VM I have on the server. ISPconfig has turned my server into a read only system making it unusable. Which shouldn't be the case no matter what version of ubuntu it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uninstall ISPconfig...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access

At the # prompt, type:

`fsck -f /` # to check the file system

repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors

`mount -o rw,remount /dev/sda6` # to remount the disk r/w

`/root/ispconfig/uninstall` # to uninstall ISPconfig

`reboot` # to reboot the system

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had used `mount -o rw,remount /` in the past but i finally tried `mount -o rw,remount /dev/sda6 /` and it worked.

Comment: I now have to do `mount -o rw,remount /dev/sda6 /` overtime I boot. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Since you have a highly modified system... that is... a server config with a GUI desktop... I don't know how to help you here, as I don't really know the server part. You could start a new question for this current problem and see if somebody else can help. I'm sorry.